# Sort by comparing the sum of a double

Tags: list, haskell

```
maxSumPair :: [(Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int)
maxSumPair l = head $ sortBy (comparing auxSum) l

auxSum :: (Int,Int) -> Int
auxSum (a,b) = a+b
```

With the function `maxSumPair` and I want to calculate which of the doubles has the biggest sum.

For example, this is how it should work:

```
> maxSumPairs [(1,10),(6,6),(10,1)] 
(6,6)
```

But my function gives me (1,10) instead of (6,6). What's my mistake?

Comment: What is the problem, `6, 6` is the biggest in the list.

Comment: It was just an example. The function i wrote gives me (1,10).

Comment: `auxSum = uncurry (+)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy), by default, does the stable sort *in ascending order*. So, `head` will get the smallest pair. Instead, you can tweak the `auxSum` to return negative sum values to sort the actual data in descending order and get the head, like this

```
auxSum :: (Int,Int) -> Int
auxSum (a,b) = -(a + b)

> maxSumPair [(1,10),(6,6),(10,1)] 
(6,6)
```

If you don't want to change the `auxSum`, then use [`last`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:last) function instead of `head`, like this

```
auxSum :: (Int,Int) -> Int
auxSum (a,b) = a + b

maxSumPair :: [(Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int)
maxSumPair l = last $ sortBy (comparing auxSum) l

> maxSumPair [(1,10),(6,6),(10,1)] 
(6,6)
```

**Note:** Alternatively, you can use [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy) function, which will be highly efficient for this case (because `sortBy` would run in O(n * log n) time but `maximumBy` would finish it in O(n)), like this

```
auxSum :: (Int,Int) -> Int
auxSum (a,b) = a + b

> maximumBy (comparing auxSum) [(1,10),(6,6),(10,1)] 
(6,6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the discussion, note that you can perform reverse sorting by flipping the comparison function:

```
reverseSort xs = sortBy (flip compare) xs
reverseSortBy cmp xs = sortBy (flip cmp) xs
```

so you could have written:

```
maxSumPair xs = head $ sortBy (flip $ comparing auxSum) xs
```